# add unallocated space to extended partion

Tags: 12.04

My Primary partitions are full (4).
I have the extended partition holding my Ubuntu and its Swap.
Now, There are these two separate Unallocated spaces which have failed to be used and I cant even add them to the Extended partitions. 
Please guide me how to have them in use.
Gparted have failed.

Comment: If you can tell us what error you find when you try using `gparted` , it might be helpful. Also could you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to the question ( coz it provides a better picture of your hard-drive partitions)?

Answer (score 1):

The unallocated space must follow a partition to expand the partition into that space.  You may need to move partitions around to make this happen.  Moving partitions can take a very long time, and if the process is interrupted, your data will be lost, so make sure you backup first.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you used gparted but once you open your hard drive right click over extended, then resize, move the slider to add the unallocated space to the extended and then resize the partition you want.